# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, ascii

I'm getting this error when trying to run scrapy. I can't seem to find a way to fix it.

```html
"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character"
```

This is because of the € character i have here.

```html
 if item['Price'] == ['50,00 €', '100,00 €']:
```

When I put code = utf-8 in my settings.py, I get this error

```html
NameError: name 'utf8' is not defined
```

Comment: make sure you have `#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the top of your file

Comment: When I use this for some reason scrapy is not saving anything to csv file

Comment: there is nothing about scrapy or saving to a csv in your question so can't help you there....